# NullPointerException при вызове CallBack

Tags: java, android, callback, null

Пытаюсь сделать CallBack из фрагмента в Activity для этого создала интерфейс, Activity его имплементирует, фрагмент получает реализацию этого интерфейса в методе onAttach, в этом же методе делаю вызов колбека  - и он отрабатывает нормально. Далее, когда я пытаюсь сделать вызов этого колбека в другом методе (captureImage()) этого фрагмента, то получаю NullPointerException, в чем может быть проблема.

Интерфейс:

```
public interface UpdateBitmapPaths{
    void updateBitmap(
            ArrayList bitmappaths
    );
}
```

Фрагмент:

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment
        implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, AudioRecord.TakePictureListener, AudioRecord.SavePictureListener,
        AudioRecord.ReceivePictureListener {

    private String TAG = CameraFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    public static final String EXTRA_CAMERA_DATA = "camera_data";

    private static final String KEY_IS_CAPTURING = "is_capturing";
    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_B = 100;

    private static Camera mCamera =null;
    private ImageView mCameraImage;
    private SurfaceView mCameraPreview;
    private static byte[] mCameraData;
    private boolean mIsCapturing;
    public static Bitmap mCameraBitmap;

    private View view;
    static String[] filetime2 = new String[100];
    static ArrayList filetime3 = new ArrayList();
    AudioRecord audioRecord;

   static int clicked=1;

    private UpdateBitmapPaths bitmapCallback;
    public static ArrayList <String> bitmappaths = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (AppCompatActivity) context;
        audioRecord = (AudioRecord) context;
        bitmapCallback  = (AudioRecord) context;
        bitmapCallback.updateBitmap(bitmappaths);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment,
                container, false);

        mCameraImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_image_view);
        mCameraPreview = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.preview_view);

        RelativeLayout fragment = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment);
        DoubleTap = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), new MyGestureListener());
        mCameraImage.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);
        mCameraImage.setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener);

        final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = mCameraPreview.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mIsCapturing = true;

        if (mCamera == null) {
            try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder());
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                if (mIsCapturing) {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to open camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(4000, 3000, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_CAPTURING, mIsCapturing);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST_B) {
            if (resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (mCameraBitmap != null) {
                    mCameraBitmap.recycle();
                    mCameraBitmap = null;
                }
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                byte[] cameraData = extras.getByteArray(CameraFragment.EXTRA_CAMERA_DATA);
                if (cameraData != null) {
                    mCameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cameraData, 0, cameraData.length);
                    mCameraImageView.setImageBitmap(mCameraBitmap)
                }
            } else {
                mCameraBitmap = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("On pause method works!", "works!");
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                if (mIsCapturing) {
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to start camera preview.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    public void captureImage() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    mCameraData = data;
                    File imageDirectory = null;
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatfolder = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd",
                            Locale.getDefault());
                    imageDirectory = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +                                       "/Audio_Recorder_Picture/Picture", dateFormatfolder.format(new Date()) + "_" + FirstscreenActivity.newpressed);
                    if (!imageDirectory.exists() && !imageDirectory.mkdirs()) {
                        imageDirectory = null;
                    } else {
                        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss",
                                Locale.getDefault());
                        File file = new File(
                                imageDirectory.getPath() +
                                        File.separator + "image_" +
                                        dateFormat.format(new Date()) + ".png");
                        String filepath = file.getPath();
                            bitmappaths.add(filepath);
 // строчка, которая приводит к NullPointerException
                            bitmapCallback.updateBitmap(bitmappaths);

        }
    }

    public void takePicture() {
            captureImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void recievePicture(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mCameraImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mCameraImage.setRotation(0);
    }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
    public class AudioRecord extends AppCompatActivity implements UpdateBitmapPaths{ 

    ArrayList bitmapppaths;
    private CustomViewPagerH mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_three);
            mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test4);
            mPreviousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test5);
            mLabelPlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test6);
            mCaptureImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_image);
            mCaptureImageButton.setOnClickListener(mCaptureImageButtonClickListener);

            findViewById(R.id.capture_image).setOnClickListener(mCaptureImageButtonClickListener);

            recordButtonpause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_button);
            recordButtonpause.setOnClickListener(recordButtonListener);
            findViewById(R.id.record_button).setOnClickListener(recordButtonListener);

            chooseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_button);
            chooseButton.setOnClickListener(chooseButtonListener);
            findViewById(R.id.choose_button).setOnClickListener(chooseButtonListener);

            mPager = (CustomViewPagerH) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

            mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

     @Override
        public void updateBitmap(ArrayList bitmappaths) {
            this.bitmapppaths=bitmappaths;
        }
 private OnClickListener mCaptureImageButtonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.wtf("TAG", "First listener");

            mCaptureImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (firstslide==0) {
                        firstslide++;
                        if (fragment!=null) {
                            fragment.takePicture();
                        }
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                        updateCallback.update(CameraFragment.bitmappaths.size());
                        for (int i =0; i<CameraFragment.bitmappaths.size(); i++ ){

                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                        firstslide--;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
};
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как ни странно, что бы `CallBack` сработал, нужно на него подписаться из активности в вашем фрагменте. Как аналогия метод `setOnClickListener(this)`, подписывает Ваш класс на получение данного события, точно также, нужно сделать и с фрагментом. Можно это сделать и без интерфейса.

создайте метод в `AudioRecord`

```
public void setArrayBitmap(ArrayList bitmappaths){
// тут ваш код
}
```

и вызывайте его из фрагмента (Если активность является местом запуска данного фрагмента) так

```
((AudioRecord) getActivity()).setArrayBitmap(yuobitmap);
```

Comment: Попробовала сделать так как вы написали, все равно получаю NullPointerException во фрагменте: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.attracti.audiorecorderpicture.AudioRecord.setArrayBitmap(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference

Comment: тогда попробуйте использовать переменную audioRecord во фрагменте... Вам по сути нужно продебажить, у вас явно сам слушатель == null, так как вы ни как во фрагмент не передаете подписчика.